# Spec$(\mathbb{Z})$ not a complete variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

What does this question mean *precisely*? In the wiki entry of Arakelov theory it is mentioned that Spec$(\mathbb{Z})$ is "not a complete variety" --- What does this mean? What does it mean for a scheme to be complete?

Any reference or comment would be great.

Thanks

Wiki entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arakelov_theory

Comment: A quick google search gave me [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_variety).

Comment: Thanks. I see: the morphism from a complete variety to the point is a proper morphism. Does this mean Spec$(\mathbb{Z})$ is not complete in the sense that the map from Spec$(\mathbb{Z})$ to any one of its points is not a proper morphism?

Comment: From the scheme theoretic perspective $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ is complete (proper over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$). The problem is that $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ behave very much like $\operatorname{Spec}k[X]$ (for example, there coordinate rings are PID). The thing is, the latter may be completed to get $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ while $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ can't, though it looks like it should : there is indeed a point at infinity, but this isn't the point of any scheme.

Comment: Thank you Roland. So the "lack of completeness" comes from the analogy between Spec$(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ / $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ rather than any technical definition?

Comment: Yes but there is more : to any curve, there is a unique "smooth complete curve" associated (take the projective closure of any affine subset and normalize). The points of this "smooth complete curve" are in bijection with the valuations of the fraction field. This was once a way to take this "smooth complete curve". Valuations gives (non-archimedian) absolute values. Now absolute values (up to equivalence) on $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ are in bijection with the primes $|.|_p$, plus one "at infinity" : our usual absolute value $|.|$.

Comment: On a complete curve, any principal divisor has degree $0$. This can be expressed by $\sum_{x\in C}v_x(f)=0$. In $\mathbb{Q}$, we have an analogous (multiplicative) formula $\prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}\cup\{\infty\}}|f|_p=1$.